# What is the meaning of “Spin that record, babe!”

Tags: phrase-meaning

I live in Brazil and my native language is Portuguese. I have studied English for a while, but sometimes have some doubts. I'd like to know what this phrase means:

> Spin that record, babe!

It's a phrase from a Lady Gaga song called "Just Dance".

Comment: A "record" is a "phonograph record" -- a plastic disc with grooves on both sides that a needle rides in to "read" music off the disc and "play" it through, eg, a loudspeaker.  In order to "play" the music the disc must be "spun".

Comment: @HotLicks   vinyl not plastic :)

Comment: @MegaMark - Actually, it was copper with a coating of beeswax.  Then after that, shellac.  Then after that a thermoplastic known as PVC and informally referred to as *vinyl*.

Comment: @Hot Licks : Lol. Somebody's an audiophile or knows way too much about how records were made.  Also, I do believe that "Vinyl" is PVC's middle name, 'cos it puts the V in PVC.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - Perhaps.  But according to family lore, my aunt Polly put the P in PVC.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: There's not much we can do about your *doubts*, especially since you didn't tell us what it is that you're hesitant to believe. Your *questions*, on the other hand, we can try to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because interpretation of song lyrics is OT.

Answer (score 3):

It dates back to [vinyl records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramophone_record) that had to spin (revolve) in order to play (they started at 78 revolutions-per-minute, and ended at 33⅓ rpm) and looked like this:

[image: phonograph arm on an LP record]

Comment: @GEdgar: Woe unto you, scribes and pharisees.

Comment: @J.R.: No, 78 rpm was the standard inculcated by Emperor Hadrian. After the fall of the Roman Empire they went to 77.

Comment: @Ricky - Both 77 and 78 have been obsolete for awhile, I think, except for mixing tracks on albums by the Chipmunks.

Comment: @J.R.: Of course, considering that the issue of switching to 45 was first raised by Louis XIV. Queen Anne and Peter the Great joined their voices to his shortly thereafter.

Comment: I'll give you an Upvote if you can tell me what the marks mean on the side of the platter and if you answer the question in relation to the Lady Gaga song (cause that's what the OP is asking, dude.)

Comment: @michael_timofeev: I haven't heard any Lady Gaga songs except a fragment of something or other involving paparazzi: it didn't stick. As for the marks, I'd imagine they're for gauging and adjusting the speed: when the turntable is in motion and the speed is off (faster or slower than 33.3, or whatever) the illusion of the upper circle marks matching one of the lower circles' marks (or something) is off too. I have actually seen the owner of one of those monsters adjust the speed. He was a geek of sorts. This was a long time ago.